# How to hide Template Pages from search?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, template, m365

Modern Page templates are shown on search results. This creates a bad UX cause there's no clear indicator that is a Template on the way results are shown.

Any way, via a system field or so, to filter out Page Templates from search results?